# kivymd application crashes on android when using MDRaisedButton

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

My application works perfectly on the machine. I am using kivymd without any external libraries.

but application crashes on android when using MDRaisedButton

```
MDRaisedButton:
            text: 'Enter'
            custom_color: app.theme_cls.primary_color
            pos_hint: {"center_x": 0.5, "center_y": 0.35}
            size_hint_x: .8
            text_color: 1,1,1,1
```

When I see the Android cat I have this return:

```
11-16 08:45:56.034  1950 32332 W ActivityTaskManager:   Force finishing activity org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity
11-16 08:45:56.036  1950 32332 V WindowManager: Changing focus of displayId=0 to null from Window{16a7d70 u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
11-16 08:45:56.065  1950  9792 I WindowManager: WIN DEATH: Window{16a7d70 u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity}
11-16 08:45:56.065  1950  9792 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object '16a7d70 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
11-16 08:45:56.076  1950  7623 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_left_ActivityRecord{da6a64b u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2250} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
11-16 08:45:56.076  1950  7623 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_top_ActivityRecord{da6a64b u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2250} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
11-16 08:45:56.076  1950  7623 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_right_ActivityRecord{da6a64b u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2250} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
11-16 08:45:56.076  1950  7623 W InputManager-JNI: Input channel object 'Letterbox_bottom_ActivityRecord{da6a64b u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2250} (client)' was disposed without first being removed with the input manager!
11-16 08:45:56.082  1950  2025 W InputDispatcher: Letterbox_top_ActivityRecord{da6a64b u0 org.pdv.denky.android.kdem/org.kivy.android.PythonActivity t2250} has FLAG_SLIPPERY. Please report this in b/157929241
```

What can it be?

```
# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.1.0,kivymd==1.1.1,pillow
```

Answer (score 0):

Try kivymd=1.0.2 in the buildozer.spec requirements